# Printing list in order

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to print

```
1
22
333
4444
...  & so on until 10
```

My code:

```
for i in range(1,11): 
    print 'i'*i
```

I get the output:

```
i
ii
iii
iiii
...
```

Where am I going wrong? I need the `i` value, I tried `'%d'*i %i` but I still get the wrong output.

Answer (score 4):

You are duplicating (using the overloaded `*` operator) the string `'i'` `i` times - instead, you should duplicate the **string representation of the `i` variable**:

```
for i in range(1,11): 
    print str(i)*i
```

Comment: Well, you are not really multiplying. Rather it is an operator overloaded asterisk, which is used to repeat a given string.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi indeed - couldn't think of a better term for it. I replaced multiplying with "multiplying", to attempt to make it clearer. Not sure I really did, though

Comment: Rephrased - I think "duplicate" is more appropriate that "multiply". Suggestions for better wording are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You just had the slightly wrong symbol, single quotes instead of backticks. The latter work fine:

```
>>> for i in range(1,11):
        print `i`*i

1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999
10101010101010101010
```

I assume you saw someone else use them and didn't notice the difference? I'm not sure whether they're frowned upon, I just know that Python 3 removed them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `str(i)` :

```
for i in range(1,11):
    print str(i) * i
```

You are actually creating a string `"i"`, not using the str representation of the  variable `i`.

Output:

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999
10101010101010101010
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [21]: for i in range(1,11):
   ....:     print str(i)*i
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the string `'i'` for `i` times instead of `str(i)` for `i` times.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> print '\n'.join(str(i)*i for i in xrange(1, 11))
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999
10101010101010101010
```

This is an alternative approach using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) in order to construct the entire output first as one large string and then simply print that string.

Our goal is to first construct the string so we do so by iterating through [`xrange(1, 11)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) and doing sequence multiplication on the string version of `i` to get the required string. In Python, when you multiply a sequence by an integer n, you get a new sequence that consists of the original sequence repeated n times. Strings are sequences in Python, so this is an easy way of repeating a string n times.

Next, we join together all the string pieces with the newline character. When we have our big string, we just print it out in a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that other answer codes are less verbose, but, Just in case you **'do not'** want to typecast the *int to str*, you may use the below code, to produce the same output

```
row = 1
base_length = int(input("Base Length: "))

while row <= base_length:
    iteration = row
    while iteration:
        print(row,"  ", end= '')
        iteration -= 1

    print("\n")
    row += 1
```